# using parameter max(high) or min(low) in batch file

Tags: batch-file

i want to use a command in batch file where i can find out lowest price or highest price.

batch file command :

```
@echo on    
echo "file init    
call ec2-describe-spot-price-history -H --instance-type t1.micro --start-time 2014-06-17T10:00:00 --end-time 2014-06-17T13:00:00 >> out.txt;    
echo "file written"    
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%i in (out.txt) do echo %%i    
echo "file written"    
echo "file done"
pause
```

output of the batch file

```
Type    Price   Timestamp   InstanceType    ProductDescription  AvailabilityZone
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE   0.006100    2014-06-17T10:19:16+0530    t1.micro    Windows us-east-1d
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE   0.006100    2014-06-17T10:19:15+0530    t1.micro    Windows us-east-1a
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE   0.006100    2014-06-17T10:19:15+0530    t1.micro    Windows us-east-1b
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: There is insufficient information about the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "max=0.000000"
SET "min=9.999999"
FOR /f "skip=1delims=" %%a IN (q24450870.txt) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=2" %%i IN ("%%a") DO (
  IF %%i gtr !max! (SET "max=%%i"&SET "maxline=%%a")
  IF %%i lss !min! (SET "min=%%i"&SET "minline=%%a")
 )
)

ECHO max is %max% IN %maxline%
ECHO min is %min% IN %minline%
GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q24450870.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Your data contains three data lines where the prices are identical, so the result appears nonsense. Also, the data presented is not the output of the batch file as claimed, but probably represents the content of the datafile `out.txt`

Without further information, it's pure guesswork what your goal actually is.

---

Using that process, unchanged other than using your latest data, I obtained this result:

```
max is 0.006100 IN SPOTINSTANCEPRICE 0.006100 2014-06-29T22:45:09+0530 t1.micro SUSE Linux us-east-1b 
min is 0.002100 IN SPOTINSTANCEPRICE 0.002100 2014-06-29T22:45:08+0530 t1.micro Linux/UNIX us-east-??1b
```

Which appears to be max and min, so sorry- can't see your problem. need more info.

Comment: but i will share my out put what i shared earlier                                         out put Type                                                      Price Timestamp InstanceType ProductDescription AvailabilityZone
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE 0.003100 2014-06-30T05:07:12+0530 t1.micro SUSE Linux us-east-1d
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE 0.005100 2014-06-30T02:43:23+0530 t1.micro SUSE Linux us-east-1a
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE 0.006100 2014-06-29T22:45:09+0530 t1.micro SUSE Linux us-east-1b
SPOTINSTANCEPRICE 0.002100 2014-06-29T22:45:08+0530 t1.micro Linux/UNIX us-east-1b
i w not able to share the reslt as it w 2 long

Comment: the command is running and i am able to see the max price . bit not able to see lower price . could u help me .